# TypeORM : invalid usage of the option next in the fetch statement. entity framework

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am getting error using NestJs, TypeORM with mssql driver.
I am getting it by hitting by using the postman.

GET : http://localhost:5000/customer/6

I am getting the Error AS :

[Nest] 11704   - 05/25/2020, 12:04:32 AM   [ExceptionsHandler] Error: Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement. +3863ms
QueryFailedError: Error: Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.
    at new QueryFailedError (E:\nest-api\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at E:\nest-api\node_modules\typeorm\driver\sqlserver\SqlServerQueryRunner.js:232:61
    at _query (E:\nest-api\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:409:25)
    at Request.tds.Request.err [as userCallback] (E:\nest-api\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:471:15)
    at Request.callback (E:\nest-api\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:56:14)
    at Connection.endOfMessageMarkerReceived (E:\nest-api\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2407:20)
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (E:\nest-api\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1279:15)
    at Parser.tokenStreamParser.on (E:\nest-api\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1072:14)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:182:13)

In service i am using the below code

```
   @Injectable()
export class CustomerService {
// Using decorator @InjectRepository for dependency injection and injecting repository to service

constructor( 
    @InjectRepository(Customer)
    private customerRepository : Repository<Customer>){}


    async GetAllCustomer()
    {
       return await this.customerRepository.find();
    }

    async AddCustomer(data : customerDTO)
    {
        const cust =  await this.customerRepository.create(data)
        await this.customerRepository.save(cust);
       return  cust;
    }

    async GetCustomerbyID(id : string)
    {
        return await this.customerRepository.findOne({ id : parseInt(id)});
    }

    async UpdateCustomer(id: string ,data : Partial<customerDTO>)
    {
        await this.customerRepository.update({ id: parseInt(id)},data);
    }

    async DeleteCustomer(id : string)
    {
        return await this.customerRepository.delete({ id : parseInt(id)});
        return {deleted : true};
    }

}
```

In the controller class of the customer has written as 
controller.ts

```
@Controller('customer')
export class CustomerController {

    constructor(private customerService : CustomerService){}

@Get()
GetAllCustomer()
{
    return this.customerService.GetAllCustomer();
}

@Post()
AddCustomer(@Body() data : customerDTO)
{
    return this.customerService.AddCustomer(data);
}

@Get(':Id')
GetCustomerByID(@Param('id') id: string)
{
    return this.customerService.GetCustomerbyID(id);
}

@Put(':id')
UpdateCustomer(@Param('id') id: string,@Body() data : customerDTO)
{
    return this.customerService.UpdateCustomer(id, data);
}

@Delete(':Id')
DeleteCustomerbyID(@Param('id') id: string)
{
    return this.customerService.DeleteCustomer(id);
}

}
```

request URL in postman
http://localhost:5000/customer/6

response
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error"
}

i just by logging : true and it is failing due to

```
 at Parser.parser.on.token (E:\nest-api\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:37:14)
query: SELECT "Customer"."id" AS "Customer_id", "Customer"."name" AS "Customer_name", "Customer"."address" AS "Customer_address", "Customer"."phonenumber" AS "Customer_phonenumber", "Customer"."age" AS "Customer_age", "Customer"."isEmployeed" AS "Customer_isEmployeed" FROM "customer" "Customer" WHERE "Customer"."id" = @0 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS
ONLY -- PARAMETERS: ["6"]
query failed: SELECT "Customer"."id" AS "Customer_id", "Customer"."name" AS "Customer_name", "Customer"."address" AS "Customer_address", "Customer"."phonenumber" AS "Customer_phonenumber", "Customer"."age" AS "Customer_age", "Customer"."isEmployeed" AS "Customer_isEmployeed" FROM "customer" "Customer" WHERE "Customer"."id" = @0 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT
1 ROWS ONLY -- PARAMETERS: ["6"]
```

Please let me know if i missed any details.

Comment: hi there, can you show us the customer repository's method implementation ?

Comment: Can you show me your request in postman

Comment: It's not GET but PUT

Comment: This is not the answer you're looking  for, btw watch out bercause in your controller you should `await` for `this.customerService.UpdateCustomer` to return something.
Back to your question: can you try `await this.customerRepository.update(parseInt(id),data);` ?

Comment: please find the method implementation and Postman request at the bottom it is Get with id for particular  customer.   <b> @0xCAP </b> i am parsing it into integer in repository.

Comment: The point is not where you are parsing `id` as integer, but the fact that you're putting it into an object. Without `parseInt` it should look like `await this.customerRepository.update(id, data);`

Comment: @0xCAP awaiting and returning a promise there doesn't make the difference, the result is the same: a promise is returned.  In fact, there's even an [ESLint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await) to not do that.

Comment: @c1moore I actually didn't read the whole examples he pasted, mb. Btw the anwer would be feeding .update() an integer as the first parameter.

Comment: attached the query by making logging : true in ormconfig file, it is failing on converting to query it self.

Comment: I find out the workaround for that and it is working fine for me... instaed of using **.FindOne** if  we will use like **return await this.customerRepository.find({where : {id : id}});** it is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the below workaround for my application. If any one get better solution than that please post.

Instead of using below code for fetching one record.

```
async GetCustomerbyID(id : string)
    {
        return await this.customerRepository.findOne({ id : parseInt(id)});
    }
```

use that.

```
 async GetCustomerbyID(id : number)
    {
        return await this.customerRepository.find({where : {id : id}});
    }
```

Now insted of using the **findOne** i am using **find** with **where** clause and you can put the filter based on your need. 
Thanks all for your effort...